# Is there a way to prevent events from slotted elements in the light dom from propagating througth the shadow dom?

Tags: ecmascript-6, web-component, dom-events, shadow-dom

## The problem

I have a complex element P from a third party library that listen to events triggered by user interaction. I want to write a Web component that contain P  in its shadow dom, and using the slot mechanism, I want any element C elements put in W’s light dom to be displayed at some place in P.

My problem is the following : For element C that are interactive, I would like to have events propagating directly to the light dom, without triggering any eventual event listener in P.

## What I tried

Instead of directly addint the slot in P herachy,I tried to add the slot in an other element that I created, add this element in P herachy and stop the event propagation when bublling in this element. In term of encapsulation, this element is not a parent of the sloted element from the light dom, but doing so still prevent the events to reach W.

## Exemple reporducing the situation

The external lib creating P (P.js) :

```
export function P(container) {
    const superComplexInnerHierachy = document.createElement("div")

    superComplexInnerHierachy.textContent = "Some P lib's interactive stuff"

    superComplexInnerHierachy.addEventListener(
        "click",
        () => console.log("I'm the third party P lib, I do stuff on click.")
    )

    container.append(d1)

    const thingsIDo = {
      add : (elem) => {
        superComplexInnerHierachy.append(elem)
        superComplexInnerHierachy.append("More P lib's interactive stuff")
      }
    }

    return thingsIDo

}
```

The web compenent W that I'm trying to write (W.js):

```
import {P} from "P.js"

class W extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){

        this.attachShadow({mode : "open"})

        this.value = "Something else"

        // Create the lib stuff in the shadow root
        this.p = P(this.shadowRoot)

        // Add a slot in P's hierachy to inject an element from the light dom
        const slot = document.createElement("slot")
        this.p.add(slot)
    }
}
customElements.define("w-component", W);
```

The html snippet where W is used.

```html
<script type="module" src="W.js"></script>

<w-component>
   <div name="an_interactive_element_usupecting_of_P">
      <input type="button" value="Button A">
      <input type="button" value="Button B">
   </div>

</w-component>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("w-component")
        .addEventListener("click", evt => {
            console.log(`${evt.target.value} was clicked`)
        })
</script>
```

## Behavior

### The behavior of the current code

**When clicking on A**

`I'm the third party P lib, I do stuff on click.`

`Button A was clicked`

**When clicking on things added by P**

`I'm the third party P lib, I do stuff on click.`

`Something else was clicked`

### What would like to have

**When clicking on A**

`Button A was clicked`

**When clicking on things added by P**

`I'm the third party P lib, I do stuff on click.`

`Something else was clicked`

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to **capture** the event before it is transmitted to the Shadow DOM, by setting the 3rd parameter of `addEventListener()` to `true`.

If you detect that it comes from a slotted element and you can handle it by yourself, call `stopPropagation()` to prevent its propagation.

```
document.querySelector("w-component").addEventListener("click", evt => {
    console.log(`${evt.target.value} was clicked`)
    if ( evt.path.findIndex( elem => elem.localName === "slot" ) !== -1 )
        evt.stopPropagation()
}, true )
```

Comment: I'm not totally satified with this slution. I think the solution you propose aslo prevent the event to propagate inside the sloted element. In my case those element are more complex than simple button, they may need to have events propagate internaly.

Comment: @ThibaultUrien then capture the event in the custom element and reemit a custom event if needed